# Any way to recover a .MYD file from .MYI and .frm files?

Tags: mysql, database, recovery

I currently have "MYI" and "frm" files of a really important database. When I use the "strings" command on the "MYI" file I can actually see readable data and the "frm" data seems to be fine.
Is there any way that I can use these two files to maybe recreate the "MYD" file? My end goal here is to view the database or execute SQL commands on it. So anything that helps with that would be fine by me.

I tried to view the database in XAMPP but it seems to be corrupted. (Because I'm missing the "MYD" file of course)

[What my directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZoBT.png)

Comment: I am guessing this is an older version of MySQL? So what version

Comment: I think .frm is the table format, .myi is the indexes, and .myd is the actual table data.  so you are probably out of luck unless the data you are most interested in is indexed, and even then it will be difficult to produce anything useful

Comment: Ah alright, thank you anyways @ysth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .frm file is for table metadata. .MYD and .MYI files only pertain to the MyISAM storage engine. The .MYD file has whole rows, stored in the order they were inserted (roughly). The .MYI file has index data structures.

So the .MYI file only includes some of the columns of your table — those that were in the indexes defined for the table. Columns that were in the data but not part of any index are not in the .MYI file. It's typical that only a few columns of a table are indexed. So at best, if you were able to recover strings from the .MYI file, it would lack many of the columns that were in the .MYD file.

I don't know of any tool to "recover" data from .MYI files. It is an internal file format, generally readable only by the MyISAM storage engine code. You can read about the details of the format here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/the-myi-file.html

You would be better off restoring data from your most backup. If you don't have a backup, then may just be a learning experience about the importance of making backups.

Comment: just curious if you happen to know, does the aria storage engine also use .MYI/.MYD files?

Comment: well yeah I guess this was a wake up call to make more backups.

Comment: I am not sure about Aria. I've never looked into using it, since I don't use MariaDB.